# Change icon in StackNavigator header dynamically

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Given StackNavigator options listed below:

```
static navigationOptions = {
title: 'Main', 
headerRight: (
    <MaterialIcons name="grid-on" size={26}/>
  ),
};
```

I want to change the icon in the headerRight after user press it, how can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { state } = navigation
    if (state.params.yourCheck) {
      return {
        title: 'Your Title',
        headerRight: (
          <Button
            title={'Button1'}
            onPress={() => {
              // do something
            }}
          />
        ),
      }
    } else {
      return {
        title: 'Your Title',
        headerRight: (
          <Button
            title={'Button2'}
            onPress={() => {
              // do something
            }}
          />
        ),
      }
    }
  }
```

This is how you can change the state param value

```
  this.props.navigation.setParams({ yourCheck: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

With React Navigation 5 you can do this like this,

```
this.props.navigation.setOptions({
  headerRight: () => <Button
      onPress={() => this._scanNearByDevices()}
      title= "Scan"
      color="#000"
    />
});
```

Whenever you want to update your header button you can use the above code to update dynamically.